# How can I solve the errors of my code in VHDL?

Tags: syntax-error, vhdl, quartus

I have made a code that does arithmetic and logic operations.But when I do the compilation, the report shows that I have many syntax errors.I am a beginner in VHDL, I really do not know how to correct these mistakes,can you give me some advise?

```
1  library ieee;
2  use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
3  use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
4  use ieee.numeric_std.all;
5
6  package arith_operations is
7   constant size: integer :=8;
8   constant select_bits: integer :=3;
9   procedure add( x,y: in bit_vector(size-1 downto 0);
10                 sum: out bit_vector(size-1 downto 0); c_out: out bit );
11  procedure sub( x,y: in bit_vector(size-1 downto 0);
12                   d: out bit_vector(size-1 downto 0); c_out: out bit );
13  function inc(x: in bit_vector) return bit_vector;
14  function dec(x: in bit_vector) return bit_vector;
15  end arith_operations;
16
17 package body arith_operations is
18  procedure add( x,y: in bit_vector(size-1 downto 0); sum: out bit_vector(size-1 downto 0);
19               c_out: out bit);
20  variable s: bit_vector(size downto 0);
21  begin
22   s:= "0" & x + "0" & y;
23   sum:= s(size-1 downto 0);
24   c_out:= s(size);
25  end add; 
26  procedure sub( x,y: in bit_vector(size-1 downto 0);sum: out bit_vector(size-1 downto 0;
27                c_out: out bit);
28  variable s: bit_vector(size downto 0);
29  begin 
30    s:= "0" x + not("0"& y) + ((size-1 downto 0)=>"0") & "1";
31    d:= s(size-1 downto 0);
32    c_out:= s(size);
33  end sub;
34  function inc(x: in bit_vector(size-1 downto 0)) return bit_vector is
35  variable x1: bit_vector(size-1 downto 0);
36  begin
37    x1:= x + ((size-2 downto 0)=>"0") & "1";
38    return x1;
39  end inc;
40 
41  function dec(x: in bit_vector(size-1 downto 0)) return bit_vector is
42  variable x1: bit_vector(size-1 downto 0);
43  begin
44    x1:= x + ((size-1 downto 0)=> "1"); 
45    return x1;
46  end dec;
47 end arith_operations;
48
49 use work.arith_operations.all;
50
51 entity alu is
52 generic(delay :time);
53 port( x,y: in bit_vector(size-1 downto 0);
54       function_select: in bit_vector(size-1 downto 0);
55      f: out bit_vector(size-1 downto 0);
56 end alu;
57
58 architecture behave of alu is:
59 begin
60   p0: process(x,y,function_select) 
61   variable f_out: bit_vector(size-1 downto 0);
62   begin
63     case function_select is
64      when "000" => add (x, y, f_out); f<= f_out after delay;
65      when "001" => sub(x, y, f_out); f<= f_out after delay; 
66      when "010" => f <= inc(x) after delay; 
67      when "010" => f <= dec(x) after delay; 
68      when "100" => x or y after delay; 
69      when "101" => not x after delay; 
70      when "110" => x and y after delay; 
71      when "111" => x xor y after delay; 
72     end case function_select;
73   end process p0;
74 end architecture behave;
```

also these are the mistakes :

```
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at Alu.vhd(21) near text "begin";  expecting "end", or a declaration statement
Error (10396): VHDL syntax error at Alu.vhd(25): name used in construct must match previously specified name "arith_operations"
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at Alu.vhd(26) near text "procedure";  expecting "entity", or "architecture", or "use", or "library", or "package", or "configuration"
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at Alu.vhd(56) near text "end";  expecting an identifier ("end" is a reserved keyword), or "constant", or "file", or "signal", or "variable"
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at Alu.vhd(60) near text ")";  expecting ":", or ","
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at Alu.vhd(62) near text "begin";  expecting an identifier ("begin" is a reserved keyword), or "constant", or "file", or "signal", or "variable"
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at Alu.vhd(64) near text ")";  expecting ":", or ","
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at Alu.vhd(65) near text ")";  expecting ":", or ","
```

I tried to correct them ,but it looks like some of the errors do not make sense because I have all the punctuation marks that errors show.Also I have set the file as top-evel entity.

Comment: If you really are lost you can always remove as much code as possible and add a few lines (as little as possible) each time.  Look at examples on the WWW and check/compare the syntax character-by-character.

Comment: Arithmetic is not available on bit_vectors for any of the included packages. You will need to include numeric_bit_unsigned for arithmatic using bit_vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were still a few syntax errors in your code. You should be able to solve them by yourself but some of the notes that I've made:

1. Declaring a procedure inside a package body should start with e.g. `procedure add(...) is`. The line should not end with a semicolor, you've done this correctly with functions.
2. With the expression `(size-1 downto 0)=> "1"` you've probably wanted to make a vector of size "size" containing only 1s? To achieve this, use an expression e.g. `x1'range => '1'` where x1 can be a vector variable of which size is `size`.
3. You use `+` operator for `bit_vector` type which is not defined. You probably intended to use `std_logic_vector` type because you imported `ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all`. Alternatively use `numeric_bit_unsigned` package.

   Btw. this package is not supported so you might want to change the data type with a conversion to `unsigned` and use `ieee.numeric_std.all` package instead.
4. There might be errors about undeclared types etc. Check how you use the `use` statements.

There are other small syntax errors as well (and some logic errors, I think) but you should be able to solve them after these fixes by reading the error messages.

Comment: arithmetic can be done on bit_vector in the numeric_bit_unsigned package from VHDL 2008. There is no signed package.

Comment: @Tricky right, I've updated that bit into the answer.